# How show a formula in the next cell - Libreoffice

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice

I have a formula in a cell that computes a value. Now, I wanted to show the formula on the adjacent cell as a check point to make it very visible. This way anyone can check it's correct on the meeting.

This is a simplified case:

[image]

The red cell shows the formula entered on the cell on the left (value `4.0`).

How do I create the red cell?

Comment: Also have a look at https://ask.libreoffice.org/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Use the formula function

Let's say you have the formula in the cell B2. You want to display it in C2.

Type in the cell C2

```
=FORMULA(B2)
```

This will result in:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks.